# Mapping over array items doesn't render all elements

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

after I update an answer in my object it becomes undefined. So it doesn't fit the rest of my application,
what I have in the begginging:

```
0
:
{answers: Array(5), category: {…}, description: null, legacyName: null, name: null, …}
1
:
{answers: Array(3), category: {…}, description: null, legacyName: null, name: null, …}
2
:
{answers: Array(3), category: {…}, description: null, legacyName: null, name: null, …}
3
:
{answers: Array(3), category: {…}, description: null, legacyName: null, name: null, …}
4
:
{answers: Array(2), category: {…}, description: null, legacyName: null, name: null, …}
```

what I have after the change:

```
0
:
undefined
1
:
undefined
2
:
undefined
3
:
undefined
4
:
undefined
```

The reducer:

```
function updateObject(oldObject, newValues) {
  return Object.assign({}, oldObject, newValues);
}

function updateItemInArray(array, questionId,answerId, newValue) {
  return {
    project: array.map(item => {
      if(item.id !== questionId) {
        return item;
      } else {
        item.answers.map(answer => {
          if(answer.id !== answerId) {
            return answer;
          } else {
            updateObject(answer, { value : newValue})
          }
        });
      }
    })
  }
}


export function project(state = [], action){

  switch(action.type){
    case 'PROJECT_FETCH_SUCCESS':
      return action.project; //initialize the project from a fetch
    case 'ANSWER_UPDATE_SUCCESS':
    {
      return updateItemInArray(state, action.questionId, action.answerId, action.newValue); //Want to change a value in one object in the array of arrays
    }
    default:
      return state
  }
}
```

What I want to do is to find the array in the array and then find the object in that array to change it's value. But for some reason it returns undefined. The functions that I'm using I saw in the redux documentation: 
https://redux.js.org/recipes/structuring-reducers/refactoring-reducers-example

Comment: `return updateObject(answer, { value : newValue})`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not returning from the else condition inside the map function

```
function updateItemInArray(array, questionId,answerId, newValue) {
  return {
    project: array.map(item => {
      if(item.id !== questionId) {
        return item;
      } else {
        // need a return statement here
        return item.answers.map(answer => {
          if(answer.id !== answerId) {
            return answer;
          } else {
            updateObject(answer, { value : newValue})
          }
        });
      }
    })
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks dude, this was the answer to my questions, but I also were needed to combine this with the comment that @The Reason did

Comment: This eat up 5 hours of my life, all my console logs were spitting out the correct info, but the concat was not getting any return from my comparison results. Thank you @Shubham